# how to convert in url " _" to "-" using htaccess?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a URL that looks like:

```
url.com/rom_date/ct_8/first_0
```

How would I go about converting that URL to

```
url.com/rom-date/ct-8/first-0
```

How do I go about making friendly URLs in PHP?

Comment: You start with Google.

Comment: @NehaSinha: Did you try the linked answer provided by Marc?

Comment: Yes and it's worked

Answer (score 2):

With htaccess you can change your first link to the second like this :

```
#put me in the global htaccess file 
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([^_/]+)_([^_/]+)/([^_/]+)_([^_/]+)/([^_/]+)_([^_/]+)/?$ /$1-$2/$3-$4/$5-$6 [L,NC]
```